# Why is nginx disconnecting my download? (timeout?)

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, timeout

I have an nginx server that serves files, sends requests to php, and also proxies to a node.js backend server. This node.js server serves up file downloads, and does an awesome job. It does throttling and can hang on to the download for hours with no issues. This was tested by directly connecting to the node.js port, which is currently still bound to the external interwebs. I'd like to change that, however, so I need to have nginx handle the proxying. Before node, we had a php script to provide the same download functionality, and this script had no problem running for hours (while sucking up major resources and at time crashing the server), all behind nginx.

So, I changed the file download location do proxy to node.js and set, what I think, are the timeout values to allow infinite length downloads.

```
location ~ ^(/my/download/.*)$ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337$1$is_args$args;

  send_timeout 12h;
  proxy_read_timeout 12h;
  proxy_send_timeout 12h;
}
```

I believe these values could be as low as 60s or even less, as the times are supposedly (according to nginx docs) times between reading or sending, not totals. Since the download is constantly getting new data, it should be fine with low values. However, since it's not working, I wanted to make sure that this was not the issue. I didn't add a connect timeout, since node.js is on localhost and so the connection time should be negligible (unless node is busy, which I know it isn't).

For some unknown reason, nginx decides that it really is taking too long with this download and just severs the connection. I know this, since as soon as I remove nginx from the equation, everything works forever.

Why is nginx timing out, or for some other reason disconnecting? I checked the logs and there are no errors (maybe I can set some option to log timeouts??).

I'm quickly balding from ripping my hair out...

**Edit:** Here's the end of the debug log of one failed download:
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv: fd:32 -1 of 4096
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 event timer: 32, old: 1382596647084, new: 1382596647364
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 post event 00007F73AD1ED558
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 post event 00007F73AD0EF558
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 delete posted event 00007F73AD0EF558
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream request: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream dummy handler
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 delete posted event 00007F73AD1ED558
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream request: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
    2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream process non buffered upstream

```
******************************

2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv: fd:32 4096 of 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http output filter "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http copy filter: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 image filter
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 xslt filter body
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http postpone filter "/my/download/somefile.huge?" 0000000000EDDC00
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000EDC610, size: 4096 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter limit 0
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 writev: 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter 0000000000000000
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http copy filter: 0 "/my/download/somefile.huge?"

******************************

2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv: fd:32 -1 of 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 event timer del: 32: 1382596647084
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 event timer add: 32: 43200000:1382596647404
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 post event 00007F73AD1ED558
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 post event 00007F73AD0EF558
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 delete posted event 00007F73AD0EF558
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream request: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream dummy handler
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 delete posted event 00007F73AD1ED558
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream request: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http upstream process non buffered upstream

******************************

2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv: fd:32 4096 of 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http output filter "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http copy filter: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 image filter
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 xslt filter body
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http postpone filter "/my/download/somefile.huge?" 0000000000EDDC00
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000EDC610, size: 4096 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter limit 0
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 writev: 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http write filter 0000000000000000
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 http copy filter: 0 "/my/download/somefile.huge?"

******************************

2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv: fd:32 -1 of 4096
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2013/10/23 21:37:27 [debug] 23708#0: *21 event timer: 32, old: 1382596647404, new: 1382596647444
```

The *******'s are mine to separate the blocks (so it's easier to see them)
As you can see, there's nothing indicating any change in the rhythm (no extra timer event or such).

Also, on a different download, the end of the log is:

```
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 image filter
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 xslt filter body
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http postpone filter "/my/download/somefile.huge?" 000000000122F2F0
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000000000122DD00, size: 4096 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:4096
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http write filter limit 0
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 writev: 4096
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http write filter 0000000000000000
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http copy filter: 0 "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 recv: fd:22 -1 of 4096
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 event timer del: 22: 1382595684239
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 event timer add: 22: 43200000:1382595685518
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 post event 00007F9FD73D93B8
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 delete posted event 00007F9FD73D93B8
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http upstream request: "/my/download/somefile.huge?"
2013/10/23 21:21:25 [debug] 11960#0: *33 http upstream dummy handler
```

Note that in this download, the block size I send to nginx from node.js is 128k, so that the recv's will succeed many times in a row before a delay happens. However, it should be normal for a recv to return -1, it just means nginx has to wait a few ms for the next block (the download is throttled, so there are purposely built-in delays).

The strange thing here is that the 2 download logs have different endings: The 128k block download ends in the "http upstream dummy handler", but the 4k block download ends in "event timer: 32, ...."

I still have no idea why nginx is stopping this. If I disconnect from the client, nginx will show an error in the log: "client disconnected, not sure what he was thinking" or something like that. What this tells me is that nginx is Not disconnecting because it thinks that the client stopped. Also, there's no indication it stopped because it thinks node.js isn't responding.

If anyone has any idea what this could be, please share.

**Edit**: it seems nginx is restarting. I see the pid of the master process is different after a failed download. Still investigating why.

Comment: any solution for your problem ?

Comment: Probably, yes. I may have fixed it somehow, but this is 2 years old and I can't say I remember. Note that nginx was restarting. Maybe it was being killed by some overzealous script, like a build script. If that's so, then that means it was never nginx.